# Is sum of matrices of a faithful representation degenerate?

Tags: matrices, finite-groups, representation-theory

I noticed that for faithful representations of some groups sum of corresponding matrices is degenerate. E.g. for a representation of $S_2$ which permutes basis vectors we have
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
+
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Analogously for other permutation groups.

For the representation of cyclic groups by rotations we have sum of matrices to be zero. The same is for [the quaternionic group](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Faithful_irreducible_representation_of_quaternion_group#Representation_table),for [the $M16$ group](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Faithful_irreducible_representation_of_M16) and standard representations of permutation groups.

Is it just a coincidence or not?

I know that any finite dimensional representation of a finite group decomposes uniquely to a direct sum of irreducible ones. So the problem can be reduced to irreducible representations only. Also I know that representations of finite groups are equivalent to unitary ones. But all that doesn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\rho : G \to GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ be a complex representation of a nontrivial finite group $G$, and put
\begin{align*}
\pi = \frac{1}{\#G}\sum_{g\in G} \rho(g)\in M_n(\mathbb{C}).
\end{align*}
Then
\begin{align*}
\gamma \pi(x) = \frac{1}{\#G} \sum_{g\in G} \rho(\gamma g) x = \frac{1}{\#G} \sum_{g\in G} \rho(g) x = \pi(x)
\end{align*}
for any $\gamma\in G$. Thus $\pi$ is the projection onto the subspace $(\mathbb{C}^n)^G\subset \mathbb{C}^n$ fixed pointwise by $G$ (acting by $\rho$). If $G$ does not act trivially on $\mathbb{C}^n$ (e.g., $\rho$ is faithful), that subspace is a proper one, and so $\pi$ is degenerate.